# Accessing value of progressEvent for progress bar from axios to set it to the Loader component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar

I'm working on a React application with a backend in .NET Core 6. I need to implement a dynamic progress bar on the frontend that reflects the progress of backend API calls. The progress bar should show the percentage dynamically, and the loader should display 100% and close when the entire response is received.

I can't share the actual code due to confidentiality, but I'll provide details about what I've accomplished so far.

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NewConfiguration from "./PopUpComponents/NewConfiguration";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import {GetDummyData} from "../Api/ApiCalls";
import store from "../redux/store";
import Loader from "./Shared/Loader";

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
//all dispatch methods.
  };
}

export default class Home extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  static displayName = Home.name;
  static contextType = appContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen: false,
      caseStatusDropDownOpen: false,
      selectedCaseStatus: "",
      dummyData: {},
      loading: true,
      importExportFields: [],
      valueListMasterData: [],
      selectedProductStatus: {},
      secondloader: true,
      showInactiveProducts: false,
      loadingText: "Loading... Please do not close the browser",
      progressPercentage: 0,
    };
  }
  // componentDidMount() {}
  componentWillMount() {
    GetDummyData(sessionStorage.getItem("CaseNumber"), { onDownloadProgress: this.handleProgressPercentage }).then((response) => {
      this.props.dummyData(response.data);
      this.props.addNewConfigProductGroup(response.data.productRangeCode);
      sessionStorage.setItem("CustID", response.data.custGUID);
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        "DummyData",
        JSON.stringify(response.data)
      );
      this.setState({
        dummyData: response.data,
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
    });
  }
  handleProgressPercentage = (progress) => {
    this.setState({ progressPercentage: progress });
  };
  render() {
    const {
      loading,
      loadingText,
      progressPercentage,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div >
        <Loader
          isLoading={showDocumentLibrary === true ? false : loading}
          loadingText={loadingText}
          progress={progressPercentage}
        />

        {showDocumentLibrary === true ? (
          <div className="mainPaneFront" id="mainPaneFront">
            <DocumentRepository showCheckBoxes={false}></DocumentRepository>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div
            hidden={this.state.caseData.caseNumber === null || !this.context.UserPrivileges.PRODUCT_OVERVIEW_PAGE}
            className="mainPaneFront hideMainFrontPage"
            id="mainPaneFront"
          >

            <AnotherComponent
              DummyData={this.context.DataInffo}
              hideLoader={this.hideLoader}
              showInactiveProducts={showInactiveProducts}
            />
          </div>
        )}
        {/*This is for Product Overview Loader*/}
        <Loader
          isLoading={
            this.state.secondloader === false || showDocumentLibrary === true
              ? false
              : !loading
          }
          loadingText={loadingText}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Home = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home));
```

**loader.js **

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Loader = (props) => {
  const { isLoading, loadingText, selectedClass, setTime, progress } = props;
  // const { isLoading, loadingText, progress } = props;
  const [newProgress, setProgress] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      setProgress(progress);
    }
  }, [isLoading, progress]);

  return (
    <div id="loaderDiv" hidden={!isLoading} className={"main-loader-section " + selectedClass}>
      <div className="loader mb-2"></div>
      <div className="loader-progress">{Math.round(newProgress)}%</div>
      <span className="ml-2" style={{ fontSize: "16px" }}>{loadingText}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

**APIcalls.js **

```
import axios from "axios";
import fetchXMLS from "../data/fetchXML.json";
var data = require("../appsettings.json");
var env = data.CurrentEnvironment;




axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = apiKey;
axios.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";

export const GetDummyData = (caseNumber, { onDownloadProgress }) => {
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: window.location.origin + "/api/dataHere/GetDummyData",
    params: { caseNumber },
    onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
      const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
      // Calculate the current percentage based on the progress event
      const percentage = Math.round((loaded / total) * 100);
      onDownloadProgress(percentage)
      console.log("GetDummyData Percentage" + percentage)
    },
  });
};
```

this is the code which I am using. It just show 0% and the data is displayed. I want to to shoe the whole loading on the screen.

I have tried using the OnDownloadProgress and OnUploadProgress in the axios call but it didn't as expected.